# ScrollView decreases my ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I would like to make a layout with a search area and a ListView into a ScrollView for both.

But the ListView doesn't fill the layout ><

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt_procura_cliente"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="10" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2.3"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:text="Procurar" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_clientes_visitas"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: remove the scrollview. As said by blackbelt listview has its own scrolling.

Comment: But I want the whole layout goes down , when I scroll down.

Comment: If I set the height of the ListView (android:layout_height="500dp" ) it works like I want but , it could have some empty space in the bottom.

Comment: using layoutweight for listview. it will fill space at the bottom. I din't get your commnet-- But I want the whole layout goes down , when I scroll down

Comment: If I remove the ScrollView  the search area is gonna be fixed in the top and I don't want that. When a scroll down the search area should disappears.

Comment: most of the apps have a search at the top. ur listview should scroll. I am not sure why you want search to scroll down. I don't know if this works. you can remove the view . when scrolling add view at the bottom. I haven't tried. I am sure others can give a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for it,  here:[How can I put a ListView into a ScrollView without it collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing/3495908#3495908)

Works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

You can not put a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`. The ListView has its own scrolling.